# How can I copy a file from the inside of a Phar to the outside

Tags: php, phar

I would like to know if is it possible to copy a file from inside of a Phar to outside of it.

And how to do it if appropriate.

The copy function will be called from this same Phar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Phar::extractTo` to do this.

The [documentation for this](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.extractto.php) states the following:

> Phar::extractTo — Extract the contents of a phar archive to a directory

With the example usage:

```
public bool Phar::extractTo ( string $pathto [, string|array $files [, bool $overwrite = false ]] )
```

Note: Your `php.ini` file must have `phar.readonly` to be set to `0` for this to work.

An example usage from the docs:

```
<?php
try {
    $phar = new Phar('myphar.phar');
    $phar->extractTo('/full/path'); // extract all files
    $phar->extractTo('/another/path', 'file.txt'); // extract only file.txt
    $phar->extractTo('/this/path',
        array('file1.txt', 'file2.txt')); // extract 2 files only
    $phar->extractTo('/third/path', null, true); // extract all files, and overwrite
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle errors
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it should help.
Also, do you think I can call this function from the Phar that I want to extract?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're saying, you should be able to. I've edited my answer to include an example usage for clarity

Comment: Thanks, a last question, PHP documentation refers to `$pathto` as **Path within an archive to the file to delete**.
Is this an error or no? I need to be able to extract the file several times from the Phar, like it would be possible to do with a **ZIP** or **RAR**.

Comment: I see, your original question didn't state that :) In this context _extract_ refers to literally taking the file out of the Phar, so once it has been moved the original file inside of the Phar it will be deleted. If you need to 'copy' it many times it might be worth keeping track of the location of the original file in a variable, and then using another PHP function to copy it such as http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: Thanks again, if so I will manage to not store the files inside the Phar